# Consuming WCF service using ksoap2

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to consume wcf service in my android project but I am getting the following error

```
05-24 02:44:35.995: E/TAG(1731): Error: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <HTML>@2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@b41da630)
```

---

```java
    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "getWeather";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/getWeather";
    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:44482/Service1.svc";

    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("cityName", "Karachi");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelop;
    soapEnvelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelop.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

    HttpTransportSE htp = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 15000);

    // int jumpTime = 0;
    // progress.setProgress(jumpTime);
    htp.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);
    response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelop.getResponse()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Thanks guys for your contribution but I have solved my problem. The issue was IIS Express Server in Visual Studio 2013. I was trying to access my web service from android but IIS Express was maybe not configured or something. Anyway the solution is to change your server from project properties. Change from IIS Express to **ASP.Net Application Development Server**.

**PS:** *Visual Studio 2013 does not support Visual Studio Application Development Server anymore.*

Answer (score 0):

May this help you.

```
private String getDataWebService(){
final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
final String METHOD_NAME = "getWeather";
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/getWeather";
final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:44482/Service1.svc";
try{
   SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
   PropertyInfo info = new PropertyInfo();
   info.setName("city");
   info.setValue("city_name");
   info.setType(String.class);
   Request.addProperty(info);
   SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelop= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   soapEnvelop.dotNet = true;
   soapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

   AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
   httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);
   Object response = null;
   response = soapEnvelop.getResponse()
   return response.toString();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
}

}
```

Comment: AndroidHttpTransport cannot be resolved to a type..?

Comment: Plz replace  this line AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL); by HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(YOUR_URL); may this resolve your problem

Comment: LOL.. then what's the difference between what you have posted and what I have posted in my question. I am glad that you contributed but copy pasting does not work all the time..!!

Comment: But the procedure which I written here is working at my side.